# python + tkinter: How to use Canvas for the main function and for a subfunction both?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

It should be a easy question but I just didnot find the answer.

I have made a **main function**, in which a **button** and a **line** are drawn. I have also a **subfunction**, which connects to the **button** in the main function.

By clicking the button I want to have an another line drawn into the same window, and the original line should be erased.

Here is the code I wrote. I really dont know how to finish it. Any kind of help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import Tkinter as tk

def DrawFunc():
    x1 = 20 ; y1 = 20
    x2 = 60 ; y2 = 80

    S_Canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
    S_Canvas.pack()

    S_Canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black")  # When the button is clicked, this line should be shown. And the old line should be deleted.


def Window():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x400")

    S_Canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
    S_Canvas.pack()
    S_Canvas.create_line(50, 250, 250, 70, fill="red")  # When the program is run, this line is shown.

    Frame_1 = tk.Frame(root)
    Frame_1.place(width=120, height=80, x=0, y=0)
    Button_1 = tk.Button(Frame_1, text = u"Draw", width = 20, height=10, bg= "green" ,command = DrawFunc())
    Button_1.pack()

    root.mainloop()
Window()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw in the same `canvas`, your `DrawFunc` function must know that canvas.

The quickest solution is to add a `targetCanvas` parameter to your `DrawFunc` function, and to pass it `S_Canvas`.

I might remember bad, but I think that tkinter does not support directly passing arguments to callback functions. As a workaround, you can use a lambda function:

```
Button_1 = tk.Button(Frame_1,
                     text = u"Draw",
                     width = 20,
                     height=10,
                     bg= "green",
                     command = lambda: DrawFunc(targetCanvas))
```

If however you want to reuse this command, you must define a `draw_func_command` function, that takes no argument:

```
def draw_func_command():
    global S_Canvas
    DrawFunc(S_Canvas)
```

But then, you need to declare `S_Canvas` as global...

To avoid this, the general way to implement UI elements is to declare them as classes. I am not going to develop this here though, because it's a broad topic and it's a bit beyond the question.

To delete the first line, it's a bit tricky. Actually, the `Canvas.create_line` returns an object, that is the line drawn. To delete it, you must store it in a variable, then call the `delete` function on it.

The problem with your code is that the function are not in the same class, so the variables must be passed from each other...

As for the erasing canvas problem, add a `oldLine` argument to your `DrawFunc` function, then call `oldLine.delete()` in its body.

```
currentLine = S_Canvas.create_line(50, 250, 250, 70, fill="red")
```

```
Button1 = Button(..., command = lambda: DrawFunc(targetCanvas, currentLine))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now the programm can draw the second line into the window. But would you please tell me how to delete the first line?

Comment: In order to remove the first line, I tried with a very beginners method. I draw the same line in the subfunction again, to cover onto the old line. I used the background color of the window. But the line seems move aside to another position, and I have three lines now.

Comment: @doglas You're welcome :) Still, for further application and understanding, I would recommend doing the same thing, but with objects. Hint: you should write one and only one class, which is `Window`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have to admit that I never come up with the idea to use the class method for this task. Actually I never tried with class for tkinter. But I will try. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This code works. I changed x1,y1,x2, and y2 to bigger values; otherwise, the black line is not seen because it is blocked by the green button.

```
import tkinter as tk

def DrawFunc(S_Canvas):
  x1 = 200 ; y1 = 200
  x2 = 260 ; y2 = 280
  S_Canvas.delete("all")
  S_Canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="black")  # When the button is 
  #clicked, this line should be shown. And the old line should be deleted.

def Window():
 global root
 root = tk.Tk()
 root.geometry("400x400")
 S_Canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
 S_Canvas.pack()
 S_Canvas.create_line(50, 250, 250, 70, fill="red")  # When the program is run, 
 #this line is shown.

 Frame_1 = tk.Frame(root)
 Frame_1.place(width=120, height=80, x=0, y=0)
 Button_1 = tk.Button(Frame_1, text = u"Draw", width = 20, height=10, bg= 
  "green" ,command = lambda:DrawFunc(S_Canvas))
 Button_1.pack()
 root.mainloop() 
Window()
```